# How to store JSON array variable and printing specific value. (JAVA)

Tags: java, json

To print the neccesary details we used the following command
`System.out.println(msgFromServer.data);`

Now the following details are fetched from server

```
[{id={name=XDA Studio, color=red}, angle=-0.24456912236854822, piecePosition={pieceIndex=39.0, inPieceDistance=35.797426838065036, lane={startLaneIndex=1.0, endLaneIndex=1.0}, lap=2.0}}]
```

How to store these above server messages in json array variable and print value of `angle`  alone.

Comment: Did you just put the output of three System.out.println() command? or one command gave you three lists?

Comment: sorry one command gives only one message

Answer (score 1):

msgFromServer.data seems to return a List. Your List is something like

```
List<Map<String,Object>>
```

If you use Jackson parser, you could probably convert it to a Json String using the following code:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(list);
```

I have provided code for Jackson library, you could use any other with library specific implementation and code

Comment: Well, in that case it is simple, just use one of the Json library to parse it to a Json string, like for example, I provided code for Jackson parser: http://jackson.codehaus.org/
i will also edit my answer then.. :)

Comment: can u provide little brief explanation with code example

Comment: Can you tell me what kind of object does msgFromServer.data returns?

Comment: public final Object data;

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51490/discussion-between-sambhav-sharma-and-aldo)

Comment: returns this `[{id={name=XDA Studio, color=red}, angle=-0.24456912236854822, piecePosition={pieceIndex=39.0, inPieceDistance=35.797426838065036, lane={startLaneIndex=1.0, endLaneIndex=1.0}, lap=2.0}}]`

Comment: Can you cast this Object to a List? try it.. (List<Object>)msgFromServer.data